# UITableViewAccessoryCheckMark move label inside cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

For a weird reason, in my CustomCell when I put a checkmark, the labels inside the cell are shifted to the left/right when I click on the cell...Can somebody help?

In my cellForRow method:

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone )
    {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
```

Comment: Did you created the cell using the interface builder or programmatically?

Comment: I created the cell using  IB

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes, for the cell. but event disabling it nothing change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling `autolayout` and check the autosizing value of your subviews. Make sure that the right margin is not activated. It would explain why they're being shifted when an other subview, in your case the `accessoryView`, is added.

[image: Autoresizing screenshot]

You could eventually deactivate the flexible width in some cases.